# What is the idea behind setting the attributes twice, once in html and then in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and jquery and i was looking at some code and found this to be very prevalent everywhere.

```
<ul class="items">      
<li class="item" aria-controls="item-0" role="tab"> </li>
<li class="item" aria-controls="item-1" role="tab"> </li>
<li class="item" aria-controls="item-2" role="tab"> </li>
</ul>
```

The attributes to "item" class are set in html but then they are set again in jquery. Why?

```
$(".items").find(".item").each(function () {
                    $Item = $(this);
                    $Item.attr("aria-controls", "item-" + (count));
                    $Item.attr("role", "tab");
                    count++;
                    });
```

Comment: Are you certain you are looking at the actual source html and not the browser interpretation in the developer tools? After the js runs it will update in the developer tools panel to have the attributes added. If you look at the actual source code it shouldn't have those values on the HTML as it's a wasted effort.

Comment: Are you getting the html from the source code? The HTML is the result of the javascript code (it is the output).

Comment: there is no reason to do that twice. Just set it in js is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is not actually a duplication of the code or data, what you are seeing in the HTML is the final rendering after the javascript you provided has run.

Essentially the javascript you provided is finding any child of items with the class of item and is iterating through each element. After that it is updating some attributes to change the role and aria-controls. This is an easy way to set the same attributes on multiple items or to (as shown here) append to a single item through each iteration.

```js
var count = 0;
$(".test").find("p").each(function () {
  $Item = $(this);
  $Item.attr("id", "child" + count);
  $Item.attr("class", "extended-child");
  count++;
 });
```

```css
.extended-child {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

In the above example for example, after iterating through and p child elements the class will be updated to make the text red and the ID will be set. You will notice initially there is no class however after there is a class applied. If you were to inspect this in your browser however you would see:

```
<div class="test">
   <p class="extended-child" id="child0">Hello</p>
   <p class="extended-child" id="child1">World</p>
</div>
```

However as you have seen that is not the initial HTML that was added.

**EDIT**

Below is a carbon copy of the above except I will update the HTML again. After 3 seconds the class will update changing the text color.

```js
var count = 0;
$(".test").find("p").each(function () {
  $Item = $(this);
  $Item.attr("id", "child" + count);
  $Item.attr("class", "extended-child");
  count++;
 });
 
 setTimeout(function(){
 $(".test").find("p").each(function () {
  $Item = $(this);
  $Item.attr("class", "extended-child-two");
 })
 }, 3000)
```

```css
.extended-child {
    color: red;
}

.extended-child-two {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, does that mean that it only takes the 1st execution of javascript to change the html forever?

Comment: @panarama not at all. See my edit. You can always update the html using JS again.